# TypeError: members.forEach is not a function при попытке обработки результата guild.members.fetch() Discord Api JS

Tags: node.js, discord, discord-api

`function kickall(message)` при попытке обработки результата функции `fetchGuildUsers(message)`
выдает ошибку `TypeError: members.forEach is not a function`. По советам вместо `.forEach()` пытался использовать `.each()`, результат - аналогичная ошибка. Подскажите, как обработать этот массив?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();

let config = require('./config.json');
let token = config.token; 


Client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logget in as ${Client.user.tag}!`)
})


async function fetchGuildUsers(message) {
  let Users = await message.guild.members.fetch()
              .then(console.log)
              .catch(console.error);
  return Users;
}
    
function mkick(member) {
  member.kick()
    .then(() => console.log('Kicked'))
    .catch(console.error);
}

function kickall(message) {
  let members = fetchGuildUsers(message);
    members.forEach(member => {
      setTimeout(mkick,1300,member);
    });
}


Client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content == 'kickall') {
        kickall(message);
  }
});


Client.login(token);
```

Comment: До этого я вполне успешно обрабатывал участников с помощью аналогичного кода, получая их через `guild.members.cache;` , но проблема была в том что возвращались лишь те участники, которые совершили какое либо действие за время работы бота.

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, вот здесь вы получаете `undefined`:

```js
let Users = await message.guild.members.fetch()
              .then(console.log)
```

потому что `console.log` возвращает `undefined`. Попробуйте убрать `.then(console.log)` и посмотрите, изменится ли что-то.

Если вы используете async-функции, лучше не использовать `.then()`, чтобы не запутаться. Например, можно так:

```js
async function fetchGuildUsers(message) {
  try {
    let Users = await message.guild.members.fetch();
    console.log(Users);
    return Users;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но проблема не в этом. В `let members = fetchGuildUsers(message)`; переменная принимает массив пользователей, но при попытке его обработки возникает вышеописанная ошибка.

Comment: @Exa Это странно. Потому что в таком фрагменте: `let Users = await Promise.resolve(42).then(console.log).catch(console.error); console.log(Users);` в качестве `Users` выводится `undefined`.